# Null Autowired Object in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to send and receive messages to/from an ActiveMQ topic, but when receiving and try to store the received message using an `@Autowired` object it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.example.demo.Subscriber.Subcriber.onMessage(Subcriber.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1404) [activemq-client-5.15.13.jar:5.15.13]
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.iterate(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1575) [activemq-client-5.15.13.jar:5.15.13]
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:191) [activemq-client-5.15.13.jar:5.15.13]
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133) [activemq-client-5.15.13.jar:5.15.13]
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48) [activemq-client-5.15.13.jar:5.15.13]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ConnectionFactoryConfig {
    @Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
    String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${spring.activemq.user}")
    String userName;

    @Value("${spring.activemq.password}")
    String password;

    /*
     * Initial ConnectionFactory
     */
    public static Boolean TRANSACTIONAL = false;
    private static final String MASSAGE_TOPIC = "book";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(userName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);


        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.setClientID("boo");
        connection.start();
        
        RedeliveryPolicy topicPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        topicPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(0);
        topicPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(1000);
        topicPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(false);
        topicPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(0);
        
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(topicPolicy);
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Topic destination = session.createTopic(MASSAGE_TOPIC);
        
        
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createDurableSubscriber(destination, "Listener");
        consumer.setMessageListener(new Subcriber());
        return connectionFactory;
    }


@Component
public class Subcriber implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private BookStoreService bookStoreService;

    @Autowired
    private BookStoreBooksRepo bookStoreBooksRepo;
    @Autowired
    private BookStoreRepo2 bookStoreRepo;
    BookStoreBooks bs=null;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                String s;
                try {
                    s = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
                    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BookXml.class);
                    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
                    BookXml book = (BookXml) unmarshaller.unmarshal(targetStream);
                    System.out.println(book.toString());
                    Bookstore bs1 = new Bookstore(6, "Amazon", "London");
                    bs = new BookStoreBooks();
                    bs.setSid(bs1);
                    bs.setBid(book.getId());
                    bs.setBn(book.getName());
                    System.out.println(bs.getBn());

//null pointer "trying to save object to DB using @Repository
                 bookStoreBooksRepo.save(bs);
                    
                    
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JAXBException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }
    }
```

Comment: add a comment..

Comment: So that means `bookStoreBooksRepo` is `null`. This object is supposed to be "autowired" by Spring. The issue is certainly *not* related to ActiveMQ. I updated your question to make this more clear.

Comment: You are creating an instance of `Subcriber` yourself instead of using a Spring Managed instance. Closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null